# Pass a var in a function and then change the original var in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, parameters

I'm trying to create a reusable function that can take a global variable as a parameter, and then change that variable so that other functions can use it.  However my understanding is that parameters created for a function are scoped only to that function, so I won't be able to change my global variable.

The function needs to be able to take different vars as a parameter (see lines 9 and 14). How can I get this to change myVar on Line 1 so that other functions can read it?

Thanks for the input!

```
1.   var myVar1:Boolean;
2.   var myVar2:Boolean;
3.
4.   myMc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMC1Clicked);
5.   myMc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMC2Clicked);
6. 
7.   function onMC1Clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
8.   {
9.       toggleState(myMc1, myVar1, myFunction);
10.  }
11.   
12.  function onMC2Clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
13.  {
14.      toggleState(myMc2, myVar2, myFunction);
15.  }
16.
17.  function toggleState(mc:MovieClip, _switch:Boolean, funct:Function):void
18.  {
19.      switch (_switch)
20.      {
21.          case false:
22.          _switch = true;
23.          mc.gfx1.visible = true;
24.          mc.gfx2.visible = false;
25.          break;
26. 
27.          case true:
28.          _switch = false;
29.          mc.gfx1.visible = false;
30.          mc.gfx2.visible = true;
31.          break;
32.      }
33.      funct();
34.  }
35.
36.  fuction myFunction():void
37.  {
38.      trace('fired');
39.  }
```

Comment: Since you've made it a global variable, that means all the functions already have access to it, so there's no need to pass it between them. Just set `myVar` directly from within the `toggleState` method.

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified that I want to be able to pass in different vars into the function, so I can't set 'myVar' direction from within the function.  I've edited the post to clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: In AS3, objects that belong to the primitive data types (which includes Boolean, Number, int, uint, and String) behave as if they were passed by value, not reference. You would need to wrap the primitives into a non-primitive type, such as an object, which would then be passed by reference. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, 
In AS3, objects that belong to the primitive data types (which includes Boolean, Number, int, uint, and String) behave as if they were passed by value, not reference. You would need to wrap the primitives into a non-primitive type, such as an object, which would then be passed by reference. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html

So instead of `toggleState(myMc1, myVar1, myFunction);`

you would do `toggleState(myMc1, {bool:myVar1}, myFunction);`

And your function would look like this:

```
function toggleState(mc:MovieClip, myBoolObject:Object, funct:Function):void
{
    var _switch:Boolean = myBoolObject.bool;
    switch (_switch)
    {
        //etc...
    }
}
```

BUT...

Since your MC's both behave the same way, I'd suggest consolidating some code using this approach instead:

```
//MovieClips are dynamic classes, meaning you can dynamically add properties to them
myMc1._toggled = false;
myMc2._toggled = false;

//You can share the same event handler for both buttons
myMc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMCClicked);
myMc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMCClicked);

function onMC1Clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
   //Get the clicked button
   var mc:MovieClip = evt.currentTarget as MovieClip;
   toggleState(mc, myFunction);
}

function toggleState(mc:MovieClip, funct:Function):void
{
    //change the button state 
    mc._toggled = !mc._toggled;
    mc.gfx1.visible = !mc._toggled;
    mc.gfx2.visible = mc._toggled;
    funct();
}

fuction myFunction():void
{
    trace('fired');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This saved me about 50 lines of duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the function take an object and a property name (string), and then make changes to the object's property using [array access (`[]`)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access) syntax. For example:

```
function toggle(object:Object, property:String):void {
    object[property] = !object[property];
}

var object:Object = { checked: true }

trace(object.checked); // true

toggle(object, "checked");

trace(object.checked); // false
```